# How to avoid memory leaks when using arraylist with for each?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, memory-leaks

```
private ArrayList<OutputInputPair> pairs = new ArrayList<OutputInputPair>();
public void process() {
    while (!stopped) {
        for (OutputInputPair pair : pairs) {
            processCommandPairs(pair);
        }
    }
}
```

first when user click stop button, `stopped = true` so, if user not click button,
always execute `processCommandPairs` method.

when stop button click

```
@Override
public void stop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "STOP memory leak");
    pairs.clear();
    pairs = null;
    stopped = true;
}
```

I have only 1 question, if user does not not click button, occur memory leak in array list is right?

if not, how to avoid memory  leak on arraylist?

thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T29jy.png)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're doing, but you appear to be fighting against the event driven programming paradigm.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `process()` method only execute, record start. when I stop button click, arraylist part not occur memory leak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `onDestroy` method of your activity and set `stopped` to true explicitly so that the while loop exits when your activity is closed and the ArrayList will be available for garbage collection.

Comment: thanks, then, if my activity not closed, occur memory leak is right ?

Comment: you can tell it memory leak if it is stored in the RAM even after you don't need it anymore. So when you don't need it anymore, you can set stopped to true, and no memory leak will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question:
"I have only 1 question, if user does not not click button, occur memory leak in array list is right?"

The answer is "No. It not right"

But I know it would truly happen in your code. And causing memory leak along with for-each loop, there are basically 3 conditions in combination (which requires to be avoid):

1. using for-each loop instead of simple for-loop
2. the for-each loop is nested inside an infinite loop (e.g. `while(true){...}` )
3. the for-each loop is looping over a collection (e.g. *ArrayList* ) instead of an array

Memory-leak will be raised under these conditions, because the following code pieced (you can check in ArrayList class) will be executed before running `hasNext()`, `next()` or other methods insider the inner class `Itr`

```
@NotNull public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

Since this code piece is being called inside the infinite loop, infinite instance of `Itr` will be created and leads to memory leak finally.

Answer (score 0):

Using a WeakReference in Android isn't any different than using one in plain old Java. Here is a great guide which gives a detailed explanation: https://community.oracle.com/blogs/enicholas/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references.

You should think about using one whenever you need a reference to an object, but you don't want that reference to protect the object from the garbage collector. A classic example is a cache that you want to be garbage collected when memory usage gets too high (often implemented with WeakHashMap).